# Upload files to google storage with Deno

Tags: google-cloud-storage, deno

I am trying to upload files to Google Cloud Storage with Deno using the npm package `"npm:/@google-cloud/storage"`but I am getting an error due to a non-compatibility between Deno and Node modules: `Error: Not implemented: crypto.Sign`

Does anyone know an alternative method to upload files to Google Cloud Storage using Deno?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Google Cloud REST API: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects?hl=en#rest-upload-objects

```js
const token = 'OAUTH TOKEN'
const bucket = 'BUCKET_NAME'

const file = await Deno.readFile('./sample.txt');

const res = await fetch(`https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/${bucket}/o?uploadType=media&name=sample.txt`, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    },
    method: 'POST',
    body: file
})

const data = await res.json();
```

To obtain a token you can use the  [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) and then refresh the token using the refresh token obtained there